# MySQL query update error, syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Got a query like that:

```
 UPDATE trails SET route = '$route', distance = '$distance', desc = '$description' WHERE route='$route'
```

It's returning this error:

```
 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc = 'Bla bla bla' WHERE route='London to Dublin'' at line 1
```

Thanks!.

Comment: Can you show me the entire query including the php?

Comment: Seems to be something wrong with the $distance variable. Please post PHP code also to detect problem.

Comment: Whoops, `desc` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first :

escape your variables like that

```
  $route = mysqli_real_escape_string ($route ) ; // if you are using mysqli
  $route = mysql_real_escape_string ($route ) ; // if you are using mysql

 and so on .. with other variables
```

and try this :

```
   UPDATE trails SET route = '".$route."', distance = '".$distance."', `desc` = '".$description."' WHERE route='".$route."'
```

obs : `desc` is reserved keyword for mysql , so use other word or make backticks for it.

Answer (score 3):

`DESC` is a reserved keyword. Quote it using back ticks:

```
UPDATE trails SET route = '...', distance = '...', `desc` = '...' WHERE route = '...'
```

By the way, you have more serious problems in your code. SQL injection for example.

Comment: Okay, how do I sort it, what do I add to make it more secure? Thanks.

Comment: Learn to use prepared statements. Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo). `mysql_*` functions are being retired.

Answer (score 2):

[This is not the correct answer.] You should escape your strings before passing them to the query.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php or here if your are using the old deprecated functions http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: The last single quote is as part of PHP error message, not the query.

Comment: Edited. Anyway, the correct answer is Salman A's. However, I thought not to delete this, as it still provides value to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE trails SET `route` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($route)."', `distance` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($distance)."', `desc` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($description)."' WHERE route='".mysql_real_escape_string($route)."'");
```

Comment: Would this stop SQL injection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php check this link about SQL injection.